# Bypassing SSL for testing local

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, ssl, cors

I have deployed a React frontend and a Spring backend on the same server, both configured with SSL. For local testing purposes, I need to bypass SSL verification. Is there a centralized way to control SSL bypass using a flag or another approach?

The goal is to have a mechanism that allows toggling SSL verification on or off during development/testing without modifying the deployed configurations.

If there are alternative approaches to handle SSL verification during local testing for a combined React and Spring application, I'd greatly appreciate the guidance.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Simply installing a self-signed certificate may be easier. You can always try and disable validation on the client if e.g. the name is not accepted; usually there are options to do that. Just saying.